# Are 401k withdrawals included in income for Medicare premiums?

Tags: united-states, 401k, medicare

How do I report 401k withdrawals to Medicare if the IRS does not report it?

Comment: Traditional or Roth?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to report your income to Medicare.  Medicare looks at your tax returns to calculate the income-based portion of your premiums.

As a result, if you take taxable distributions from your 401(k), then you will report this on your tax return, and if your total income is high enough, your Medicare premiums will adjust.

Non-taxable distributions (such as a Roth IRA or Roth 401(k)) do not affect your Medicare premiums.

Source: https://www.newsday.com/long-island/ask-the-expert-lynn-brenner-1.15457896